# numpy-stl edges not visible

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, numpy-stl

I'm plotting STL files using numpy-stl (2.4.1) line by line according to the doc on https://github.com/WoLpH/numpy-stl

My problem is, that the edges of the triangles are not visible. Hence, I cannot see inner parts from e.g. components with blind holes.

[image]

Can someone imagine a reason for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the plotting part, add the `edgecolor` keyword argument

`axes.add_collection3d(mplot3d.art3d.Poly3DCollection(your_mesh.vectors,edgecolor='k'))`